# Why tf manipulations are working only in the arbitrary function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I build a series of tensors, the manipulation functions of `tensorflow`, such as `tf.transpose(~)` or `tf.split(~)` returns an error.

**Code**

```
window = 60
len_feat= 15
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, window, len_feat]
X = tf.transpose(X, (1,0,2))

tf.Session().run(X, feed_dict={X: x}) #x has a shape (100, 60, 15)
```

**Error**

```
"shape (100, 60, 15) can't be reshaped into (60, ?, 15)"
```

However, if I build an arbitrary function such as:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, window, len_feat])
def fun(X):
    X = tf.transpose(X, (1,0,2))
    ...
```

it works well. What makes this difference?

Comment: So `fun(X)` returns `tf.transpose(X, (1,0,2))` and does nothing more than that? In this case `tf.Session().run(fun(X), feed_dict={X: x})` returns the same error as you reported before. In what situation does your code work well?

Comment: @Merlin1896 First of all, my question has been resolved.
fun(X) has more operations below as you guess.
<pre>
    def fun(X):
        L = {'weights': tf.Variables(~), dtype=tf.float32),
                'biases': tf.Variables(~)
        X = tf.transpose(X, (1,0,2))
        X = tf.reshape(X, (-1, len_feat)
        X = tf.split(X, window, axis=0)
        C = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(128)
        outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(C, X, dtype=tf.float32)
        output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], L['weights'])+L['biases']
        return output
<code>
TNX :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet you are overwriting your placeholder by the result of the transpose. This is *not* a placeholder anymore.

Note that `feed_dict` allows you to replace *any* tensor's value, not just placeholders. However because your placeholder has shape [None, 60, 15] the transpose has shape [60, None, 15]. Thus your data with shape [100, 60, 15] can't be put into this tensor because the first dimensions don't match.

You can simply fix the first snippet by renaming your variables. E.g.

```
window = 60
len_feat= 15
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, window, len_feat]
Y = tf.transpose(X, (1,0,2))

tf.Session().run(Y, feed_dict={X: x}) #x has a shape (100, 60, 15)
```

This should work just fine. The second example, where you define a function, might work due to the distinction between local and global variables. Hard to say because you didn't provide the full code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I totally understand what was the problem.